# Accessing floating point data in fragment shader opengl es

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

I'm new to shader programming, please clear my doubts.

I need to store floating point data in texture and access in fragment shader so I created  the texture in opengl es 2.0 like so:

```
GL_FLOAT Buffer[2][2][4] = {{0.0, 1.0, 2.0,  3.0}, {4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0}, 
{8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0}, {12.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0}};

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, 2, 2, 0, GL_RGBA,GL_FLOAT,Buffer);
```

In shader program

what is the output of below codes

statement 1 : `vec4 buf1 = texture2D(sampler2D, vec2(0.0,0.0));`

statement 2 : `vec4 buf2 = texture2D(sampler2D, vec2(1.0,0.0));`

From statement 1, do i get output like this ??

```
buf1.r = 0.0;
buf1.g = 1.0;
buf1.b = 2.0;
buf1.a = 3.0;
```

Please reply and Thanks in Advance

Comment: ES 2.0 does not support float textures, unless you have the `OES_texture_float` extension.

Comment: why put the data on the texture when you can send data to any shader using "uniform" variables? also float is 4 bytes already = 1 RGBA pixel

Comment: @Reto, How to add OES_texture_float extension in ES 2.0

Comment: Actually i was trying to implement dashed Lines in opengl ES 2.0 by refering link: https://hal.inria.fr/hal-00907326/file/paper.pdf. In this document they have mentioned to use two-dimensional RGBA floating-point texture to store dashed line pattern. im not getting how to store and retrieve back in shader program. pls required help

Comment: @DanP e.g. I can't send data via `uniform` because my data is too large and there's a limit on the size of uniform data that can be sent.